# Conditional Count in DataFrame with Python

Tags: python, dataframe, count

[image: DataFrame showing trend respective to date]

I want to count how many times there is:

1. "Increase" to "Increase"
2. "Increase" to "Decrease"
3. "Increase" to "Unchanged"
4. "Decrease" to "Increase"
5. "Decrease" to "Decrease"
6. "Decrease" to "Unchanged"
7. "Unchanged" to "Increase"
8. "Unchanged" to "Decrease"
9. "Unchanged" to "Unchanged"

Code must be written in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm creating a sample dataframe to work on this problem.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': np.arange(0,16), "trend": ['in','de', 'in', 
'in','in','un','de','de','un','un','de','de','in','de','in','in']})
```

[image: sample dataframe]

1st: Make a list of the column named 'trend'

```
val = list(df['trend'])
```

2nd: Create a new list and add each pair of tuples into the list. Each tuple contains the first value and its consecutive next value according to the iteration.

```
f = val[0]
list_trend = []

for x in val[1:]:
    list_trend.append((f,x))
    f = x
```

The output list will be like this 
[image: list of pairs]

3rd: By using 'Counter', you can count occurances of each unique pair from that list.

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(list_trend)
count = c.items()
```

The output will be like this 
[image: count of each unique pair]

And that's it.....

Answer (score 0):

I can think of one approach which is *not going to be very efficient* but will get the job done:

So the basic idea is to iterate over the trend column. You go making tuples like `(new_df.trend[i], new_df.trend[i+1])`. Then you use the counter to get a dictionary which would be something like this:

```
{("Increase", "Increase"): 131, ("Increase", "Decrease"): 317, ...}
```

The actual **implementation** should look something like this:

```
from collections import Counter

list_of_tuples = [] 
for i in range(len(new_df.trend) - 1):
    list_of_tuples.append((new_df.trend[i], new_df.trend[i+1]))
occurrences = dict(Counter(list_of_tuples))
```

Comment: It shows error. Most probably ''new_df.trend[i+1]'' is responsible for error